# How to avoid using JSP login page with Spring Security in JSF2?

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-2, spring-security

I'm currently using Spring Security 2.0.4 and I have the following config:

```
<form-login login-page="/login.jsp"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp"
            default-target-url="/home.jsp"
            always-use-default-target="true"
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"/>
```

Where `home.jsp` is:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>

<security:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_1">
    1
    <jsp:forward page="/panels/searchUsers.html"/>
</security:authorize>

<security:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_2">
    2
    <jsp:forward page="/panels/partnersStatistics.html"/>
</security:authorize>
```

Now, I updated my JSF version to 2.1 and I can't use JSP anymore because of deprecating in JSF2. How can I avoid the JSP page in that case? I can't just create `springsecurity.taglib.xml` as specified [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-faces.html) because of absence `org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagHandler` in the SpringSecurity 2.0.4.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't convert your old JSP into a facelet?

**home.xhtml:**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags">

    <h:head />

    <h:body>
        <security:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_1">
            1
            <ui:include src="/panels/searchUsers.html"/>
        </security:authorize>

        <security:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_2">
            2
            <ui:include src="/panels/partnersStatistics.html"/>
        </security:authorize>
    </h:body>
</ui:composition>
```

Anyway, that will keep you in **home.xhtml** address, displaying different content for each role. If you want to force a redirection you should use a security filter, as Spring Security 2.x doesn't provide [`AuthenticationSuccessHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html). Or if you prefer to use a *[meta](http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-WCAG20-HTML-TECHS-20050630/#meta_refresh)* header, you could try something like this:

```
<h:head>
    <security:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_1">
        <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=#{request.contextPath}/panels/searchUsers.html" />
    </security:authorize>

    <security:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_2">
        <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=#{request.contextPath}/panels/partnersStatistics.html"/>
    </security:authorize>
</h:head />

<h:body>

</h:body>
```